# The result of an application in localhost is pending until refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, perl, localhost

Hope I can state my problem clearly.
I develop an application on my localhost with HTML file for the interface and javascript, PHP, Perl files for the functionality. 
There is a button on the interface that should submit user input to the other files and then display the result. 
When I click that button, the result is generated after a long time. I discover now that when I click that button and then refresh the page, the result is generated! 
It seems that the result is pending. 
Also, when I click that button and open another tab in my browser and open another localhost application, the result is generated although the two application are different.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='search' onclick="jsFunction(document.getElementsByName('x1')[0].value,document.getElementById('x2').options[document.getElementById('x2').selectedIndex].value);">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function jsFunction(x1,x2) 
{
    var url = "file.php";
    var params = "x1="+x1+"&x2="+x2;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(params);
}
```

file.php:

```
$x1= (empty($_POST['x1'])) ? '' : $_POST['x1'];
$x2= (empty($_POST['x2'])) ? '' : $_POST['x2'];
echo "This echo before perl statement    ";
pclose(popen("start /b perl file.pl \"$x1\" \"$x2\"", "r"));
echo "This echo after perl statement";
```

The above two echo are displayed.

Perl file.pl: call cmd application and generate the result in files

```
open LOG, ">$dataPath/$jobid.log";
open OUT1, ">$dataPath/$jobid.string.txt";
open OUT2, ">$dataPath/$jobid.result.txt";
```

The above perl result is not generated until I refresh the browser or it take a long time to be generated.

Any clarification or help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start /b perl file.pl "$x1" "$x2"` command will return immediately the perl process has been started. It will not wait for it to complete

To also wait for the perl process to complete you need to use

```
start /b /wait perl file.pl "$x1" "$x2"
```

However, all your Perl code seems to do is to create three disk files and then exit

Comment: Amazing! Many many many thanks. You solve my problem! I spent 2 weeks diving!